# VHDL - Can't see why these two architectures produce a different RTL

Tags: vhdl

I have the following examples:

1. `architecture two of andex is
   begin
   process(abus)
   variable y: bit :='1';
   begin
       for i in 7 downto 0 loop
           y:=abus(i) and y;
       end loop;
       x<=y;
   end process;
   end;`
2. `architecture three of andex is
   begin
   process(abus)
   variable y: bit;
   begin
       y:='1';
       for i in 7 downto 0 loop
           y:=abus(i) and y;
       end loop;
       x<=y;
   end process;
   end;`

The only difference between the two architectures is the location of the variable initialization.

The first architecture produces this RTL:
[image: RTL 1]

Why is there a feedback path ? y is known for the first loop iteration and every iteration there after.

I had expected it to produce an 8 bit AND gate like the 2nd architecture does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first, `y` is set to a default value of 1 at start-up time.  In the second, `y` is set to an initial value of 1 each time the process runs.

The first carries the resulting value of `y` over to the next time it runs, the second doesn't but starts with `y` equal to 1.  Hence the feedback.

In C it's the equivalent of something like this:

```
int y = 1;
void doSomething() {
    y = y + 1;
}

int y;
void doSomething() {
    y = 1;
    y = y + 1;
}
```

In the first, each time `doSomething()` is called `y` is incremented.  In the second, each time `doSomething()` is called `y` is set to 1 and then incremented, so always ends up as 2 regardless of how many times you call `doSomething()`.

Answer (score 0):

Variables keep their state across "runs" of the process, so moving the initialization up means that it is initialized once.